# Boost dijkstra string edge weight

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, dijkstra, boost-graph

is it possible to use string value instead of double properties
`typedef adjacency_list < vecS, vecS, directedS, property<vertex_name_t, string>, property < edge_weight_t, string> > Graph;`
My goal is to use the dijkstra algorithm.
PS: I already tried replacing the double with string and it generates an error within the algorithm.

```
std::vector<vertexd> P(num_vertices(g));
std::vector<string> d(num_vertices(g));
vertexd s = vertex(0, g);

dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, s,
    predecessor_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(P.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g))).
    distance_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(d.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g))));
```

Error:

> Error 13  error C2664: 'D boost::closed_plus::operator ()(const T &,const T &) const' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'const std::basic_string,std::allocator>' to 'const D &'  C:\boost_1_58_0\boost\graph\dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp 190

Comment: Since the weights are amounts in any unit anyways, what is the goal storing them as strings? Are you, perhaps having a different issue that prevents you from storing the weights properly?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have a string property.

No, dijkstra requires

> a weighted, directed or undirected graph for the case where all edge weights are nonnegative

So the weight is required to be numerical. Of course, if you can implement arithmetic operations and `std::numeric_limit<>` for your property type it might be fine (but you really have to scratch your head before doing that).

**UPDATE** _Actually, it turns out this documentation simplifies a bit, and you can actually override zero, comparison and combining for your weight type. See the [linked sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cd72d7263f8c259) in the comments (HT @cv_and_he)_

So, I hate to be that guy, but: **why**.

**Since the weights are amounts in any unit anyways, what is the goal storing them as strings? Are you, perhaps having a *different issue* that prevents you from storing the weights properly?**

---

That said, here's a way:

Using `transform_value_property_map` you can transform strings to doubles on the fly:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c96374f708d787eb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dag_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Weight = std::string;
//using Weight = double;

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
        boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string>,
        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, Weight>
    > Graph;

using vertexd = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

Graph generate();

int main() {
    using namespace boost;

    Graph g = generate();
    std::vector<vertexd> P(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<double>  d(num_vertices(g));
    vertexd s = vertex(0, g);

    auto to_double = [](Weight const& v) { return lexical_cast<double>(v); };

    dijkstra_shortest_paths(
        g, s, 
         weight_map  (make_transform_value_property_map(to_double, get(edge_weight, g)))
        .predecessor_map(make_container_vertex_map(P))
        .distance_map(make_container_vertex_map(d))
    );

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", get(vertex_name, g));
    dp.property("label",  get(edge_weight, g));
    write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, g, dp);
}

#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <random>

Graph generate() {
    using namespace boost;

    std::mt19937 prng { std::random_device {} () };
    Graph g;
    generate_random_graph(g, 10, 20, prng);

    for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        put(vertex_name, g, v, "vertex" + std::to_string(v));

#if 0
    // in case `Weight` is double
    auto gen_weight = [&, dist=std::uniform_real_distribution<Weight>(0,1)] () mutable -> Weight {
        return dist(prng);
    };
#else
    // in case `Weight` is std::string
    auto randchar = [&, dist=std::uniform_int_distribution<>('0','9')] () mutable -> char { return dist(prng); };

    auto gen_weight = [&] () {
        Weight tmp(3, ' ');
        std::generate(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), randchar);
        return tmp;
    };
#endif

    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
        put(edge_weight, g, e, gen_weight());

    return g;
}
```

Outputs the graph randomly generated, e.g.:

```
digraph G {
    vertex0->vertex5  [label=503];
    vertex0->vertex8  [label=653];
    vertex0->vertex8  [label=931];
    vertex1->vertex6  [label=022];
    vertex1->vertex8  [label=536];
    vertex1->vertex5  [label=400];
    vertex1->vertex4  [label=056];
    vertex3->vertex8  [label=555];
    vertex4->vertex7  [label=052];
    vertex4->vertex6  [label=542];
    vertex4->vertex3  [label=024];
    vertex5->vertex7  [label=595];
    vertex5->vertex8  [label=850];
    vertex7->vertex4  [label=464];
    vertex7->vertex9  [label=484];
    vertex8->vertex0  [label=274];
    vertex8->vertex1  [label=131];
    vertex8->vertex6  [label=529];
    vertex9->vertex1  [label=239];
    vertex9->vertex3  [label=362];
}
```

Which is rendered as

[image]

Comment: "Why?" indeed. [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cd72d7263f8c259) seems rather silly.

Comment: @cv_and_he Lol. That's actually kinda cute! I assume `std::less<std::string>` kicks in for comparisons. Works for this graph :)

Comment: That's the default for `distance compare`. I've just realized that the default for `distance_zero` is also appropriate (and so it isn't required).

Comment: Well. That made my answer partially wrong. I've amended the opening claims :) Cheers

Comment: Apparently, simply changing `distance_inf` makes the default `distance_combine` also [work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8f370f981d2f7be). Of course in this case it's silly, but it could be interesting for other, more useful ones.