# BGL Fruchterman Reingold Force Directed Layout

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am trying to run the `fruchterman_reingold_force_directed_layout` algorithm on a `boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge>` graph.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/fruchterman_reingold.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random_layout.hpp>

typedef boost::rectangle_topology<> RectTopology;
typedef RectTopology::point_type point;

struct Vertex {
  Vertex(int i) : index(i) {};

  int index;
  point position;
};

struct Edge {
  double weight;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge> Graph;

int main() {
  Graph graph;

  auto vertexIdPropertyMap = boost::get(&Vertex::index, graph);

  Vertex n1(0);
  boost::add_vertex(std::move(n1), graph);

  Vertex n2(1);
  boost::add_vertex(std::move(n2), graph);

  Vertex n3(2);
  boost::add_vertex(std::move(n3), graph);

  boost::add_edge(boost::vertex(0, graph), boost::vertex(1, graph), Edge(), graph);
  boost::add_edge(boost::vertex(0, graph), boost::vertex(2, graph), Edge(), graph);

  boost::minstd_rand gen;
  RectTopology rectangleTopology(gen, -25, -25, 25, 25);

  boost::random_graph_layout(graph, boost::get(&Vertex::position, graph), rectangleTopology);
  boost::fruchterman_reingold_force_directed_layout(graph, boost::get(&Vertex::position, graph), rectangleTopology);

  return 0;
}
```

When compiling, the first error is the following:

```
error: forming reference to void
         typedef value_type& reference;
```

I have done some research and apparently this is due to the fact that it is a `listS` vertex list - with `vecS` it works.
However, I still want to use a `listS` and apparently it is [possible](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/graph/test/layout_test.cpp):

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/fruchterman_reingold.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random_layout.hpp>

enum vertex_position_t { vertex_position };
namespace boost { BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY(vertex, position); }

typedef boost::rectangle_topology<> RectTopology;
typedef RectTopology::point_type point;

struct simple_edge {
  int first, second;
};

int main() {
  enum { A, B, C };
  simple_edge triangular_edges[2] = {
    {A, B}, {A, C}
  };

  typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS,
    // Vertex properties
                                boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int,
                                                boost::property<vertex_position_t, point> >,
    // Edge properties
                                boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>> Graph;

  Graph g(&triangular_edges[0], &triangular_edges[1], 3);

  boost::minstd_rand gen;
  RectTopology rect_top(gen, -25, -25, 25, 25);

  boost::random_graph_layout(g, boost::get(vertex_position, g), rect_top);
  boost::fruchterman_reingold_force_directed_layout(g, boost::get(vertex_position, g), rect_top);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that I don't want to use the "old-style" properties but the [bundled properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) instead. [Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) someone was attempting something similar, but the `fruchterman_reingold_force_directed_layout` does not offer this index map if I am not mistaking.

Comment: You can indeed use an index map with the [`vertex_index_map` named parameter](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/fruchterman_reingold.html). I think `boost::fruchterman_reingold_force_directed_layout(graph, boost::get(&Vertex::position, graph), rectangleTopology,boost::vertex_index_map(vertexIdPropertyMap));` should work.

Comment: thanks man, that answers my question - if put your comment into an answer I will mark it as solved :)

Comment: My attempt to make an answer would basically be repeating [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907760/minimum-spanning-tree-with-boost/39919999#39919999) changing a couple of names.

Comment: I do have a short follow-up question: if I use a `std::string` for the index (instead of an `int`) I get the error message: `error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference*, std::vector<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, std::allocator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference> > >' and 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>')
     inline R operator[](key_type v) const { return *(iter + get(index, v)) ; }`. What can I do about that? Thanks!

Comment: You could do something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878147/boost-dijkstra-string-edge-weight/34879202#34879202) with the index map instead of the weight map.

Comment: like so? `auto convert = [](const std::string& s) {
    return boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
  };
  auto map = boost::make_transform_value_property_map(convert, boost::get(&Vertex::index, graph));

  boost::fruchterman_reingold_force_directed_layout(graph, boost::get(&Vertex::position, graph), rectangleTopology, boost::vertex_index_map(map));`
Here I get a memory error - I am kind of struggling here, thanks for the help.

Comment: That should work as long as your indices are "0", "1",...,"n-1". If you have a different numbering scheme you'll need to map your indices to [0,num_vertices-1].